# Swift: Views not adjusting to programmatic constraints

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, ios-autolayout

I have a view that I am making hidden at the bottom of the screen, and want the scrollView above it to adjust and fill the void space.

The view at the bottom of the screen is a GADBannerView and has a fixed height of 50 (bannerHeight). The scroll view above it has a constraint to the bottom of the container that equals 50 (scrollConstraint). See photo.

[image]

In viewDidLoad is am setting these constraints to the following:

```
bannerHeight.constant = 0
scrollConstraint.constant = 0
```

This is causing the bannerView did disappear but the scroll view is staying in it's original position and not filling the void space.

Comment: I have 2 suggestions: try putting your code in viewWillAppear and make sure translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false for both banner and scroll views. Sometimes constraints are not fully calculated in viewDidLoad.

Comment: You need to use the `bannerHeight.constant` as the value for the `scrollConstraint.constant`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force the superview to take into account the change of the constraint because this does not happen automatically. Add your code to viewDidLayoutSubviews() instead or simply call view.layoutIfNeeded() after you set the constants to 0 in the viewDidLoad().

If this does not work, you can try this alternative approach:

Go to your Storyboard and click on the scroll view's bottom constraint (the blue line that gives the scroll view its bottom constraint of 50). In the Attributes Inspector you should be able to see details about your constraint, it should look something like this

[image: Attributes Inspector]

In the field that asks for an Identifier, give it the name "ScrollViewBottom" or whatever name you like.

Now loop over all the constraints that make up your scroll view and use the identifier name to find the correct one and change it's constant as follows

```
    for constraint in yourScrollView.superview!.constraints {

if constraint.identifier == "ScrollViewBottom" {
    constraint.constant = 0
}
}
```

Finally, force the view to take into account of this change by calling the following straight after

```
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
```